# Add auto increment and auto decrement column in oracle 10g

Tags: java, plsql, oracle10g

I would like to add a column to oracle database which increment automatically after inserting a record.And it should be decrement automatically when deleting a record.This field is used for store a sequence number of a table headings and that headings should be able to re-order therefore there shouldn't have any gaps between number sequence.I have tried with TRIGGER and SEQUENCE but it didn't work.Are there any way to use PL/SQL to this.Actually what I want is to shift the sequence numbers when deleting a record.

eg:row 1,row 2,row 3,row 4,row 5 if we delete row 3, the sequence should be row 1,row 2,row 3,row 4 and record which was at row4 should come to row 3 and so on..

I am using jsp-servlet technology.If there any way to do this by using java that's also good.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm thinking `update`, `order by`, and `rownum` put together should give you what you want.  (You're not doing this to your PK right?)

Comment: No this is not a PK field.But after deleting a record in the middle of the sequence the rest of sequence should be re-arranged.Is this possible?

Comment: The Oracle sequence can't be re-arranged but you could implement the your own one. But surely it's the waste of time.

Answer (score 3):

No; there is no easy way.

Whatever you do with sequences they'll [*never* generate a gap free sequence of numbers](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:530735152441), a perfect *1, 2 .. n*. Even if they did there's no way of automatically re-generating a sequence for an entire table, or set of rows within a table, without re-generating it from scratch. Simply put if you delete row 3, you need to update *all* records with a sequence number higher than 3. This is obviously ridiculous.

I do not see *why* you want to do this, however, assuming you do my "answer" would be to not store this information in your table at all. For those queries that require this column generate it on the fly using the analytic function [`row_number()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions156.htm#SQLRF06100). For instance:

```
select column1, column2, row_number() over ( order by <whatever> ) as my_sequence
  from my_table
```

This assigns a unique number to each row in the order given in the `ORDER BY` clause.

You could also put this in a view so you don't even need to remember to put it in the query and you're certain that it's been generated in the exact same manner each time.